# IntelliJ IDEA adding numbers to project name

Tags: intellij-idea

When I "Create a new project from existing sources" in IntelliJ IDEA, it adds `_####` to the end of the project name, where `####` is a seemingly random 4-digit number.

This happens with this version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.5281.24, built on June 12, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.5
```

**I know how to rename it, but how can this be disabled?**

Comment: Could you please provide the exact steps to reproduce it?

Comment: I create a new project from existing sources, where I select a `build.sbt` for a minimal Scala project, in the open dialogue window that pops up. That's it. Are you an IntelliJ IDEA maintainer?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open bug logged](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13806) for SBT subsystem in IntelliJ IDEA. Please [follow](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) it for updates.

It appears that import doesn't complete properly for some reason.

UPDATE: [SCL-13617](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13617) is the correct issue to follow.

Comment: This issue isn't relevant to numbers being added to the end of a project name.

Comment: @Neil from the issue description: "I notice that Intellij have the project a name of its own - web_3075 while the name of my project is TestProject".

Comment: You're right, sorry I didn't notice from the description. I added some notes.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior was a workaround for another bug and will be changed in the 2018.2 release of the Scala plugin. Instead the import chooses the project directory name as project name.

Comment: Why would the project name fail to detect in my case when it's explicitly set in the `build.sbt` file? It's in `lazy val projectSettings = Seq(name := "actual-project-name")` in my case.

Comment: The bahavior is deliberate to avoid some problems with importing (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13617)